# Invariant subspaces concept - linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

Why are invariant subspaces called invariant?
Normally invariant in mathematics means something that doesn't change.

Suppose we have a linear map $T:V \to V$

Also suppose $P$ is a proper subspace of $Q$, and $Q$ is proper subspace of $V$ i.e. $P \subset Q \subset V$.

I mean $P \neq Q$ and $Q \neq V$.

Now if $T$ maps $Q$ to $P$, then $Q$ is called invariant subspace w.r.t. the linear map $T$.

But $Q$ is not really invariant in the usual sense, is it?
Because under the action of $T$ the subspace $Q$ changes (it "shrinks" so to say) to $P$, and $P \neq Q$.

**Example:**

$V = \mathbb{R}^3$
$T((x,y,z)) = (x,0,0)$
$P = \{(x,0,0)\}$
$Q = \{(x,y,0)\}$

Comment: we could flip your question around.  Suppose $T$ is not surjective (for example consider the case of $\text{im }(T)=P$) but we have still written $T:V\longrightarrow V$.  Now is your vector space $V$ in fact $T$-invariant?  Why or why not?  The same argument then applies when we restrict $T$ to the vector (sub)space of $Q$.

Comment: @user8675309 Well, in that case I would say V is not T-invariant (in the usual sense of the word invariant). Because T changes/shrinks V to P. That's exactly the point of my question.

Comment: in the example I give, you are confusing the codomain of $T$ with the image of $T$